# minimum line height to ensure text is not cut off

Tags: css, fonts

Is there a standard for line height that ensures that a text is not cut off at the bottom or at the top irrespective of the setting (font family, font weight, font size, etc)?

A potentially reasonable value that one may think of may be `100%`, or `1`, but if I do `line-height: 100%`, or `line-height: 1`, the descend of letters like `g`, `y` are cut off at the bottom depending on the font. In my particular setting, `line-height: 1.2` looks like the actual minimum.

Is there any (presumably relative) value for `line-height` that ensures that a part of a character is not cut off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`line-height: normal`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) which is the default:

> **normal**
>
> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based
> on the font of the element. [...]

This leaves it up to the browser to determine the optimal line height based on factors such as font family, style and weight. See following example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("p").each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height();
    $("<span style='background: #FC0;'></span>").text(" (" + h + "px)").appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

```css
/* for Open Sans demo */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: normal;
}
.font-1 p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.font-2 p {
  font-family: monospace;
}
.font-3 p {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<blockquote>
  All paragraphs have same font size. However, their &quot;normal&quot; line height vary depending on font face and other factors such as whether bold or italic text is present on the line box. Results vary across browsers as well.
</blockquote>
<div class="font-1">
  <p>Normal text</p>
  <p>Normal text and <strong>strong text</strong></p>
  <p>Normal text and <em>emphasized text</em></p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="font-2">
  <p>Normal text</p>
  <p>Normal text and <strong>strong text</strong></p>
  <p>Normal text and <em>emphasized text</em></p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="font-3">
  <p>Normal text</p>
  <p>Normal text and <strong>strong text</strong></p>
  <p>Normal text and <em>emphasized text</em></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle example. I realized it now.

Comment: For some reason this default line-height setting was not working for me for a flex-item that needed to have a single line of text. The only way I could get the tail of the "g" to not get cut off was to set the line-height to `1.3em`, which I know is a hack...

Comment: It's not a hack @allieferr 1.3em is jsut equal to 1.3 without unit. The browser sets the line height to something between 1.2 and 1.4 when set to "normal" depending on the font family used